# PyPlot showing additional unknown data on plots

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have created a figure with two subplots, and on both there is a triangle of data which I cannot account for.

My code is:

```
first, second, third, fourth, fifth, sixth, seventh, eighth = simulation(1000)
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(2, 1, sharex=True, sharey=True, figsize=(24, 24))

ax1.plot(first, second, third, fourth)
ax2.plot(fifth, sixth, seventh, eighth)

ax1.set_title('Hearer Index', fontsize=35)
ax1.xaxis.set_tick_params(labelsize=20)
ax1.yaxis.set_tick_params(labelsize=20)
ax1.plot(first, color='orange', alpha=0.3, label='First')
ax1.plot(second, color='blue', alpha=0.3, label='Second')
ax1.plot(third, color='red', alpha=0.3, label='Third')
ax1.plot(fourth, color='green', alpha=0.3, label='Fourth')
ax1.set_ylabel('Frequency', fontsize=35)
ax1.grid()

ax2.set_title('Speaker Index', fontsize=35)
ax2.xaxis.set_tick_params(labelsize=20)
ax2.yaxis.set_tick_params(labelsize=20)
ax2.plot(fifth, color='orange', alpha=0.3, label='First')
ax2.plot(sixth, color='blue', alpha=0.3, label='Second')
ax2.plot(seventh, color='red', alpha=0.3, label='Third')
ax2.plot(eighth, color='green', alpha=0.3, label='Fourth')
ax2.set_xlabel('Generations', fontsize=35)
ax2.set_ylabel('Frequency', fontsize=35)
ax2.grid()

fig.savefig('Question2.pdf')
fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.25)
```

Where first, second, third, fourth, fifth, sixth, seventh, and eighth are lists.
[image]

I want to be able to create the same figure, but without the predominantly orange/blue data on the left side of each subplot

[image]

Edit: I have added a picture of the same plot when the `ax1.plot(first, color='orange', alpha=0.3, label='First')` and `ax2.plot(fifth, color='orange', alpha=0.3, label='First')`

Comment: Your question is unclear. You don't want to plot the orange and blue curves? It is not unknown data. You are plotting it `ax1.plot(first, color='orange', alpha=0.3, label='First')`

Comment: I thought I was being explicit enough in referring to the triangle of data on the left of each subplot, rather than the data on the rest of the graph; if it is that part of the code plotting the data I don't know why it is being plotted twice in two different ways

Comment: You are plotting in the first two commands x vs y. Later you plot only one variable

Comment: Do you know how I should alter the code in that case? I'm not overly sure what you mean

Comment: It’s hard to give answer without having a runnable code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mistake I made was doing:

```
ax1.plot(first, second, third, fourth)
ax2.plot(fifth, sixth, seventh, eighth)
```

which was unnecessary as I went on to plot them again later in the code.